# Approach to get count of one table field having count of another table field equals zero

Tags: mysql

using Mysql---i have to get the count of providers having feedback records equals to zero group by month, i don't know how to frame this question to search in google 
i have 7 tables topic,attendee,feedback,date,student,branch,provider, following gives model of these tables

```
    **feedback**:
            id -  12
            attendee_id - 32
            comment - good learning from him
            created - 2012-03-08 01:12:46

            **attendee**:
            id - 32
            student_id - 345
            topic_id - 128
            created - 2014-01-07 07:50:38
            class - topic


     **student**:
            id - 345
            branch_id - 56
            created - 2012-07-11 09:47:35

            **provider**:
            id - 67
            name - narik
            created - 2010-01-19 01:30:58

            **branch**:
            id - 56
            name - vize creators
            provider_id - 67
            created - 2010-01-19 01:30:58


             **topic**:
                id - 128
                name - photography
                group - photo
                created - 2010-01-19 01:30:58

    **desc date:**
    +-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | date  | date             | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
    | week  | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | month | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | day   | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | year  | varchar(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
    +-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

here is what i tried

```
select count(distinct p.id),d.month,t.group
from attendee a, feedback cf, topic t ,date d,student es,branch b,provider p
where date(cf.created)=d.date and p.id=b.provider_id and year(cf.created)=2014 and a.class='TopicAttendee' and a.topic_id=t.id and t.group in ('Education','Fit','Graphics','Services') and es.branch_id=b.id and a.student_id=es.id and a.id=cf.attendee_id and cf.status='ACTIVE' and comment is not null and comment != ''
 group by d.month,es.branch_id having count(distinct cf.id)=0;
```

its giving me empty set(may be because of the query fault) but i have providers who don't have feedback records in my db

Comment: can you please put here some sample data?

Comment: @VishalJAIN check now i edited its just sample data.